# How to access widgets in a subclass?

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a subclass of `QLineEdit` and I am adding a button to the right side of the widget, so I can make an *all-in-one* path browsing control. However, I need to access the button from within the `resizeEvent`, so I can properly place the button on the right side of the line edit. I get errors and I am assuming it is due to the way I have created the button.

[image]

*lineeditpath.h*

```
#ifndef LINEEDITPATH_H
#define LINEEDITPATH_H

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPushButton>

class LineEditPath : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LineEditPath(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;

private:
    QFileDialog *dialog;
    QPushButton *button;
};

#endif // LINEEDITPATH_H
```

*lineedithpath.cpp*

```
#include "lineeditpath.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

LineEditPath::LineEditPath(QWidget *parent) : QLineEdit(parent) {
    setAcceptDrops(true);

    auto button = new QPushButton("...", this);
    button->setFixedWidth(30);
    button->setCursor(Qt::CursorShape::PointingHandCursor);
    button->setFocusPolicy(Qt::FocusPolicy::NoFocus);
    setTextMargins(0,0,30,0); }

void LineEditPath::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    QLineEdit::resizeEvent(event);

    // Resize the button: ERROR
    button->move(width()-button->sizeHint().width(), 0);

}
```

error:

```
---------------------------
Signal Received
---------------------------
<p>The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.<p><table><tr><td>Signal name : </td><td>SIGSEGV</td></tr><tr><td>Signal meaning : </td><td>Segmentation fault</td></tr></table>
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: change `auto button = new QPushButton("...", this);` to `button = new QPushButton("...", this);`. the local variable is hiding the member of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto button = new QPushButton("...", this);` in your constructor does *not* initialize the `button` member variable of your class. It creates a new local variable with the same name that shadows the member variable and goes out of scope at the end of the constructor body. Your member variable is never initialized.

You want `button = new QPushButton("...", this);` - or even better; move that to your constructors initialization list rather than using the ctor body.

Using the initialization list:

```
LineEditPath::LineEditPath(QWidget *parent) :
    QLineEdit(parent), 
    button(new QPushButton("...", this)) 
{
```

You also never initialize your `dialog` member variable.

Comment: Could you demonstrate what you mean by moving it to my const unit list and the initializing of the dialog member please. I'm coming from python so stuff is a bit new to me. Thank you

Comment: @JokerMartini Sure. Answer updated with initialization list example. As for what to do about `dialog`, I don't know. I can just see you never initialize it - I have no idea what you intended to use it for or what you intended to initialize it with. All I can see is just an uninitialized variable that will blow up in your face if you use it.

Comment: The dialog itself will eventually be opened when the user clicks the Button. I haven't added that code yet :)

Comment: @JokerMartini No. I was referring to your class having a member `QFileDialog *dialog;` that I don't see you ever initializing to anything valid. So, if you ever try to dereference that pointer your program will exhibit Undefined Behaviour (probably explode). Either remove that variable if you don't need it or initialize it to something sane/usable.

Comment: After i added your suggestion, now every time i close the dialog i get this ZeroHeap error: `0x773a2010  <+0x0560>        c6 05 51 63 3e 77 00           movb   $0x0,0x773e6351`

Comment: @JokerMartini that is meaningless without a [mcve].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180078/discussion-between-jokermartini-and-jesper-juhl).